# SwitUI Wheel picker text spacing

Tags: swiftui

I am using a wheel picker in SwiftUI, with a custom larger font, and there is virtually no spacing between selections. How can i add spacing in between each selection?

```
Picker("", selection: $dqc.amountOfRandomPerDay) {
            Text("Two times")
                .font(.poppinsLight(size: 30))
                .tag(2)
            Text("Three times")
                .font(.poppinsLight(size: 30))
                .padding(10)
                .frame(height: 100)
                .tag(3)
            Text("One time")
                .font(.poppinsLight(size: 30))
                .tag(1)
        }
        .pickerStyle(.wheel)
```

[image: wheel picker]

Comment: Can you please explain more about what you want to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that you have to use `.scaleEffect(1.5)`

```
Picker("", selection: $dqc.amountOfRandomPerDay) {
            Text("Two times").tag(2)
            Text("Three times").tag(3)
            Text("One time").tag(1)
        }
        .pickerStyle(.wheel)
        .scaleEffect(1.5) // Change the number according size which you required
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this is marked as correct? This scales the entire picker, and does not increase the spacing between each item as asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SwiftUIIntrospect](https://github.com/siteline/swiftui-introspect) to vertically scale each line items view.

```
import SwiftUIIntrospect
...

let scale = CGFloat(2) // Scale factor 
Picker("", selection: $amountOfRandomPerDay) {
    Group {
        Text("Two times")
            .tag(2)
        Text("Three times")
            .tag(3)
        Text("One time")
            .tag(1)
    }
    .scaleEffect(CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1 / scale)) // <- Inverse
}
.pickerStyle(.wheel)
.introspect(.picker(style: .wheel), on: .iOS(.v16, .v17)) {
    $0.subviews.forEach { subview in
        subview.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: scale)
    }
}
```

The line `subview.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: scale)` scales the views vertically by the given factor. This increases each items height, however the text now becomes distorted.

I counter this by applying the inverse scale on the Text itself `.scaleEffect(CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1 / scale))`